# Allow rsync to write to httpd_user_content_t

Tags: rsync, selinux

We have rsyncd running as a daemon on our frontend web servers. We push web app updates out via rsync.

We're looking at cutting down the noise in auditd and fixing up some of the issues from SELinux (so one day we can turn it on properly).

At the moment we get the following messages when running rsync:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1580772908.749:172148): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=33806 comm="rsync" path="/public_html/docs/cg/html/1/.file.html.o9GVX9" dev="sda3" ino=37341 scontext=system_u:system_r:rsync_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
```

How can I allow rsync to write to these files with SELinux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different choices; from easier (but more coarse) to harder (but more specific):

- `setsebool -P rsync_full_access 1`: grant rsync full filesystem access;
- change your `httpd` file context to `public_content_rw_t`;
- write a specific selinux policy patch via `cat audit.log | audit2allow`.

Finally, you can also set `rsyncd` in permissive mode issuing `semanage permissive -a rsync_t`, but I strongly suggest avoiding that (not last because it does not get rid of selinux audit logs).

I would use the first solution, as changing a selinux boolean is the least invasive, but more obvious and immediate change.